# Override returned reference of object

Tags: javascript, immutability

I was recently looking into [Facebook's Immutable-JS](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js) library, and saw the following interesting behaviour:

```
var map1 = Immutable.Map({a:1, b:2, c:3});
var clone = map1;
```

The library ensures that `map1 !== clone`.

How is this achieved? I suspected that it is possible to override a property method that retrieves the object's reference, in the way that `Object.prototype.valueOf` does this when the object's primitive value is needed, but couldn't find anything of the sort.

Comment: I don't see any examples where they're effectively doing `var clone = map1` - they all seem to call methods on `map1`.  Are you sure that what you've asserted is true (ie that `map1 !== clone`)?

Comment: You're right, the library just makes sure that changes to either `map1` or `clone` don't mutate the other variable. The references are still equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, I think you didn't understand how it works: you don't set/unset keys with the Javascript syntax `object['key'] = value`, but instead use the `map.set('key', val)`. Then you **the programmer** must assign the resulting object to some variable because the update does not write in place: it returns a modified (and immutable copy instead). As an optimization, if the `.set()` doesn't actually change the value of the key, it returns `this`, so you can assert for reference equality

It seems that as a help to catch programming errors the library also throws errors when you try to set keys with `immutableMap.key = 'val'` (reading with `immutableMap.key` should be safe, though)

Comment: Completely missed that this behaviour would result in 2 references to the same object would effectively be copies, even though they are the same reference (because they can't update each "other"). Thanks for clarifying!